# Maintain line break in CSV file after being added via powershell script

Tags: powershell

I would like to display data in a csv file in the following format by using powershell:

Multiple data related to column one should be inserted in the same cell in column2, by simply inserting a break line. (`r`n) is not a option.

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do multiline cells in my CSV file appear with a question mark at the end of each line in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436572/why-do-multiline-cells-in-my-csv-file-appear-with-a-question-mark-at-the-end-of)

Comment: No it is not duplicate as I would like to have multiple data for the same item in the same cell and not in its own cell.

Comment: As explained in the answer to the linked duplicate: separate your multiple strings with a linefeed (`n) and that's it :)

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work as it inserts the string in a new line and under column 1.

Comment: `Export-Csv` should handle that just find. `1..3 |% {New-Object psobject -Property @{Column1=$_;Column2=$("a","b","c"-join[char]10)}} | Export-Csv `

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will give it a try. Let you know soon